# Why is my Python program printing parentheses and quotes where I don't expect them?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, f-string

I am getting this kind of weird output

My code is:

```
friends_name = ['Yashwanth','Koushik','Lalith','Narahari']
message = f"Hello buddy",friends_name[0]
print(message)
message = f'Hello buddy',friends_name[1]
print(message)
```

I am getting brackets and quotes in the output:

```
('Hello buddy', 'Yashwanth')
('Hello buddy', 'Koushik')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are printing a tuple

The variable will be a tuple because there is a value `f'Hello buddy'` and `friends_name[1]`

If you want to print them in one message

```
message = f'Hello buddy {friends_name[1]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This code: `message = f"Hello buddy ,friends_name[0]` is giving you a tuple, it is the same as `message = (f"Hello buddy ,friends_name[0])`.

What you probably want is an interpolation, in other words:
`message = f"Hello buddy {friends_name[0]}"`